# Shortcode attribute escaping

Tags: wp-editor

I'm trying to set shortcode attribute value to `' "` (single and double quote) by using escaped values `&#39; &#34;`.

Example:
`[shortcode attr="&#39; &#34;"]test[/shortcode]`

As soon as I switch to visual editor, they get converted back to `' "` and shortcode is now broken.
How does one properly escape shortcode attributes so that they can work even after switching between visual and text editor?

Comment: FWIW, I wonder if you should take one step further back and try to find a way around requiring attributes of this type at all.

Comment: A client added double quote in my shortcode and everything broke because WordPress unescaped the entered attribute value. I'm not requiring anything, I just need a way to safely escape all values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest using `keywords` for them. so you would do something like `[shortcode attr="single_quote double_quote"]test[/shortcode]`. Then, while parsing the shortcode you can change them back.